# Question about ASP.NET Cache class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I would like to use Cache for my web application.

Here is the question

I found this link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61.aspx

For that link, all the example use something like `Cache["KeyName"]="blah blah blah"`;

When I try to do the same thing, I have an error message, said `"using System.Web.Caching.Cache is a type but used like a variable"`

What should I do?

Do I have to create an instance?

**My Example**

```
string test = "123";
  if (HttpContext.Cache["test"] != null)
    test = (string)HttpContext.Cache["test"];
else
    HttpContext.Cache["test"] = test;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are getting some overlap of naming.  Be explicit and see if it works:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache["KeyName"]="blah blah blah";
```

You can also do the following in your ASP.NET codebehind:

```
Page.Cache["KeyName"]="blah blah blah";
```

or

```
this.Cache["KeyName"]="blah blah blah";
```

`Cache` is handled by ASP.NET so you just have to use it, not create it.

**EDIT:** In ASP.NET MVC you can use the following in your controller:

```
HttpContext.Cache["KeyName"]="blah blah blah";
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But Why I don't have HttpContext.Current.Cache? I have HttpContext.Cache instead...

Comment: @user361022 where are you trying to access the Cache from?  An aspx page's codebind or a class file?

Comment: It's because Cache spans multiple requests. Current refers only to the current request, which has it's own request based Cache (Items).

Comment: I am using MVC3. Just trying to do the simplest cache example.

Comment: @user361022 That is odd since it should be accessible out of the box with `HttpContext.Current.Cache` in the `System.Web` namespace.  As longs as you have an active context going (that is what `HttpContext.Current` is getting) then you should be able to access it.

Comment: @user361022 Ah MVC is not the same...  `HttpContext.Cache` is valid in MVC and useable from your controller.  Are you trying to do it somewhere other than your controller?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create an instance. ASP.NET does it for you automatically.

Use the `HttpContext.Current.Cache`.